# Clicking on a disabled control is calling the parent event in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm using VisualStudio 2013 with C# and I'm fairly new to this environment and language, so please bear with me if this is a silly question.

I have a set of buttons that reside on a panel. 
All of the buttons have onClick events, as well as the panel that the buttons sit on.  If the button is enabled then the buttons event handler is called as expected.  However; if the button is not enabled, then the panel's onclick event handler is called.

In my pre C# windows programming experience, clicking on the disabled button would have had no affect on the running program.  What's going on here, and how do I keep the parents events from being triggered?

Comment: why do you have or need a clickevent on the panel..is there anything special that happens when clicking on the panel..? if not then remove the event from the panel..

Comment: As MethodMan says. Plus I guess that is fairly standard behaviour.

Comment: The event passes through until it finds a control that can handle it.  Your button is disabled, so it passes through to the underlying Panel, which isn't, so it gets the call.  It still stands that such an event on a Panel is not obviously useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could detect it by something like:

```
        panel.Click += delegate {
            var l = Cursor.Position;
            l = panel.PointToClient(l);
            var c = panel.GetChildAtPoint(l);
            if (c == null) {
                // good
            }
            else {
                // ignore (disabled control)
            }
        };
```